# css - Padding under background image link next to text link - why?

Tags: css, hyperlink, padding

This CSS problem is killing me :-(

I cannot remove padding under a link in this page http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/test2.htm

I have reduced the problem to the bare minimum so its really clear.

You can see my issue here http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/blue.png [alt text http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/blue.png](http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/blue.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
<head>

<style type="text/css">

*
{
  padding:0;
  margin:0;
  font:15px arial;
}

div
{
  display:inline;
  height:18px;
  line-height:18px;
  background-color :blue;
}

.PageMove
{
  display:inline-block;
  background-image: url(http://www.yart.com.au/stackoverflow/page_move.gif);
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  width:18px;
  height:18px;
  line-height:18px;
}


.Text
{
 background-color :red;
 display:inline;
 height:18px;
 line-height:18px;
}


</style>
</head>


<body>

<div><a href="#" class="PageMove"></a><a href="#" class="Text">18 pixels high</a></div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Things which are `display: inline-block` are treated as as characters and sit on the baseline. There is space beneath for descenders (which you find on letters such as p, j, g and q).

Set `vertical-align: bottom` to position the element on the bottom instead of the baseline.

Answer (score 0):

why not use float?

```
<div style="width: give-it-a-usefull-width">
    <a href="..." id="pageMove" style="float: left;">...</a>
    <a href="..." id="text" style="flaot: left;">...</a>
</div>
```

Comment: … because float is even more complicated than inline-block

Answer (score 0):

I don't know where your problem is exactly stemmed from but

inline elements cannot be specified a 'height'. So your `height:18px;` for the 'inlined' `div` will be ignored.

Comment: The div with the height set is also set to display: inline, not inline-block. It is irrelevant to the problem at hand though.

Comment: Just edited the post.

Your `div` is inline, not inline-block.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue on some email templates. IE and FF did not show the blue line but emails opened on mobile devices such as iphone and android did.

Emails opened in web email clients over chrome browsers also showed the blue line.

I solved the problem by placing the image in the middle of the cell. 
align="middle"

Set the cell to align="middle" as well.

(this places the blue line behind the image and solves the problem)

On irregular shaped images (that are png, or gif) you may want to consider saving the image with a background color or converting to a jpeg on white backgrounds. Again its not the type of image that solves this, just removing a clear background and creating a solid rectangle of square block of color to hide the line solves the issue.

Good luck!

Nate Boe